# How to save XDocument to Windows Store app LocalFolder

Tags: xml, windows-runtime, linq-to-xml

I am creating a Windows Store app which reads and writes data to an XML file. The data resides in a StorageFile named 'DataFile' which I want to store in the ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder. My attempted code below produces an InvalidCastException: Unable to cast 'Windows.Storage.Streams.FileRandomAccessStream' to type 'System.IO.Stream'. What is the correct way to do this? I am using VB because of XML literals but a C# solution would be fine.

> ```
>     Dim feedXml As XElement =
>     <Feeds>
>         <%= From f In Feeds
>             Select <Feed>
>                        <FeedUrl><%= f.Url %></FeedUrl>
>                    </Feed> %>
>     </Feeds>
>     Dim xdoc As New XDocument
>     xdoc.Add(feedXml)
>     Dim app = TryCast(Application.Current, App)
>     Using fileStream As Stream = Await app.DataFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite)
>         xdoc.Save(fileStream)
>     End Using
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should convert FileRandomAccessStream to Stream using [AsStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh965622%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension method. In C# it looks like:

```
FileRandomAccessStream stream = (FileRandomAccessStream)await app.DataFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
Stream fileStream = stream.AsStream();
xdoc.Save(fileStream)
```